# Intersection of tori is a face of each torus

Tags: algebraic-geometry, convex-geometry

Let $\sigma_1,\sigma_2$ be strongly convex polyhedral cones.

Is it true that $\sigma_1 \cap\sigma_2$ is always a face of both $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$?

My guess is yes and here is my argument:

Let $u =0 \in (\sigma_1 \cup \sigma_2)^{\vee}$ be the 0 linear form.

$\forall \sigma_1,\sigma_2 \in \Sigma$, we have $\sigma_1\cap\sigma_2 = \sigma_1\cap \sigma_2 \cap (u|_{\sigma_1})^{\bot} = \sigma_1\cap \sigma_2 \cap (u|_{\sigma_2})^{\bot}$ so $\sigma_1 \cap \sigma_2$ is a  face of $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ (at least in the context of strongly convex polyhedral cones).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: As it is written it seems clear the answer is no: let $\sigma_1$ be the cone in $\mathbf R^2$ spanned by $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, and $\sigma_2$ the cone spanned by $(1,-1)$ and $(a,1)$, where $a$ is any positive number you like. Then the intersection is not a face of either cone. Maybe there is more context that you had in mind.

Comment: Thank you @LazzaroCampeotti for the counter example. indeed it doesn't work. Something is wrong in the proof, though I just stuck to the definition of a face. Maybe that supposed zero linear form is not correct?

Comment: For any linear form $u$, there is no reason that $\sigma_1 \cap \sigma_2 \cap u^\perp$ should be a face of $\sigma_1$ or of $\sigma_2$. Maybe there is a confusion about the definition of face.